# Razor: Translating a href with _blank, noopener, noreffer attributes to Html ActionLink

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to create an url with e.g `Html ActionLink` that opens in new tab and has `noopener` + `noreferrer` values for `rel``

```html
<a 
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
    href="https://localhost:5001/Gallery/View?file=@Model?.Image?.Id">
    @Model?.Image?.Title
</a>
```

But this way I have hardcoded url

I tried something like this:

```html
<a 
target="_blank"
rel="noopener noreferrer" 
href="@Html.ActionLink(item?.Image?.Title, "View", "Gallery", new { file = item?.Image?.Id })">
</a>
```

or

```html
<a 
target="_blank" 
rel="noopener noreferrer" 
@Html.ActionLink(item?.Image?.Title, "View", "Gallery", new { file = item?.Image?.Id })>
</a>
```

But it struggles with escaping html and ends with something like

```html
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" <a href="/Gallery
/View?file=123">Testimage.jpg</a>></a>
```

So, link generally works but it destroys html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, that was easier than I thought...

Solution:

```
<a 
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
    href="@Url.Action("View", "Gallery", new { file = item?.Imnage?.Id })">
    @item?.Image?.Title
</a>
```

Comment: I recommend using the [tag-helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asp-controller) for this in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

The Html.ActionLink helper will generate entire `<a>` tag. so you need to use it outside.
Simply use the following code in your page without any `<a>` tag

`@Html.ActionLink(item?.Image?.Title, "View", "Gallery", new { file = item?.Imnage?.Id }, new { target = "_blank", rel = "noopener noreferrer" })`

example

```
    <div>
       @Html.ActionLink("Testimage.jpg", "View", "Gallery", new { file = 1 }, new { target = "_blank", rel = "noopener noreferrer" })
   </div>
```

will give you the following result.

```
    <div>
       <a href="/Gallery/View?file=1" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Testimage.jpg</a>
   </div>
```